# FFMPEG - Long pause in av_read_frame

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a service that converts a m3u8 link from youtube.

I am loading the stream info then setting all but 1 video and 1 audio stream to AVDISCARD_ALL.

Everything works fine except after several seconds of playing av_read_frame blocks for 30 seconds to a couple minutes.

I'm not the best versed in ffmpeg so I'm not exactly sure what to do from here.
Extracting one of these links into ffplay works fine it seems, but I don't see what they may be doing differently? I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction of anything to try.

Attached is a callstack from when this is happening. I am not sure if anything here looks amiss.

[image]

Comment: Is it C or C++ ?

Comment: Run it in a debugger, break it when its paused and look at the callstack. Its fairly likely this'll tell you what is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: @Loufi Most of my code is C++

Comment: @MikeVine I added a stack trace, I'm looking over it, but it looks like its just waiting on the data? The weirdness is only my app has these interrupts with the link. Vlc and ffplay don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: Well that pretty much definitely blocked on a network read. Is the file local? If not how good is your connection to the remote? What kinda of playlist are you playing? Is there DRM enabled? Use a packet monitoring tool (or even task manager) to see how much bandwidth its using. It may be trying to donwload the whole file at once before processing or somehting.

Comment: @MikeVine Its coming from YouTube as in directly from them on a 200M connection. As I mentioned only my player shows this issue, ffplay doesn't seem to and neither does playing the video through the browser and I think thats what has me the most confused.

Comment: Might be better to ask on their mailing list instead?

Comment: @Shark I did. Several days ago. I decided to cross post here since there were no responses there.

Comment: Good luck then :) best thing i can say is - cross reference the ffplay's code against your own, maybe you missed something or found a bug somewhere :/